# Probability Theory (Jaynes' approach based on Cox theorem) CDF how to prove increasing monotonicity of this function?

Tags: probability, continuous-data

In his book *[Probability Theory: the Logic of Science](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf)*, Jaynes defines at page $107$ (chapter $4.5$) the continuous probability function.

To do so, he introduces a real continuous "random" variable $f$ and divides the probability space into two discrete, mutually exclusive, exhaustive events $F'$ and $F''$ defined as such:

> $$F' \equiv (f\leq q)$$
>
> $$F'' \equiv (f > q)$$

He then defines $G(q)= P(F')$ and asserts that $G$ is **evidently** monotonic increasing.

My question is how does one prove that $G$ is monotonic increasing?

I understand it intuitively but would appreciate a more proof-based insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show that $g$ is increasing as a function of $q$, we need to show that for any two $q_1\le q_2$, we have $G(q_1)\le G(q_2)$.

Note that $q_1\le q_2$, then $(f\le q_1)$ implies $(f\le q_2)$. Or in other words, if we denote $A_i:=\{\omega\in\Omega :f\le q_i \}$ for $i=1,2$, we have the inclusion of events $A_1\subseteq A_2$.

Since $G(q_1)=P(A_1)$ and $G(q_2)=P(A_2)$, the monotonicity of $G$ follows from the fact that for any two events $A$ and $B$, $A\subseteq B$ implies $P(A)\le P(B)$.